# Could exoplayer access webplayer video?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm still new with kotlin and exoplayer. i tried to set this link as my video's source but it showed some error. Is it possible to use this kind of link? Since, i thought the problem was the unsupported format so i tried using HLS but either it didnt work or i lost some step there. Please need help

```
  exoPlayer= ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000)
            .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000)
            .build()
        playerView.player = exoPlayer
        playerView.keepScreenOn = true
        exoPlayer.addListener(object: Player.Listener{
            override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int)
            {
                if(playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING)
                {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                else if(playbackState == Player.STATE_READY)
                {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                if(!exoPlayer.playWhenReady)
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updateProgressAction)
                }
                else
                {
                    onProgress()
                }
            }
        })
        val videoSource = Uri.parse("https://vanfem.com/v/8qqlyh8lmxgkn5y")
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoSource)
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.play()


    }
```

Comment: Can you please include the error itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in your example is not to a video - in fact it seems to link to web ads.

ExoPlayer won't be able to play that as it's not a valid media source.

Comment: thank you for the insight. I discovered it just now